# In Console Application the generating the PDF's takes long time and more memory and CPU usage in c#

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, console-application

I have a console application, by using this application i will create the PDF's. But it is taking 40 PDF's in one minute. And go on decreasing the Count of PDF's. As i observed in Task Manager the CPU usage is always 100% and the Memory is always increasing. I used the Multi threading concept.

How can i decrease the CPU usage and Memory and create the PDF's in a minute with more than 40 PDF's.

I am using the C# code of Muti threading.

How can we handle the CPU usage. If the CPU usage is less then more number of PDF's are generated.

Below is the Code which i used:

```
// Insert into the datatable
  dsHeader = objCustStatementDAL.GetCustStatementdetailsForPDF(IsEDelivery, 0);

  //Creating Threads
                if (dsHeader.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Thread FirstTreadPDFs = new Thread(() => objPDFsProcess.DoGeneratePDFsProcess(IsEDelivery, Cycleid, StmtRunDate, CycleType, dsHeader.Tables[0], writerLog, dsHeader.Tables[6], dsHeader.Tables[7], dsHeader.Tables[8]));
                    FirstTreadPDFs.Start();
                }


                if (dsHeader.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Thread SecondTreadPDFs = new Thread(() => objPDFsProcess.DoGeneratePDFsProcess1(IsEDelivery, Cycleid, StmtRunDate, CycleType, dsHeader.Tables[1], writerLog, dsHeader.Tables[9], dsHeader.Tables[10], dsHeader.Tables[11]));
                    SecondTreadPDFs.Start();
                }

                if (dsHeader.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Thread ThirdTreadPDFs = new Thread(() => objPDFsProcess.DoGeneratePDFsProcess2(IsEDelivery, Cycleid, StmtRunDate, CycleType, dsHeader.Tables[2], writerLog, dsHeader.Tables[12], dsHeader.Tables[13], dsHeader.Tables[14]));
                    ThirdTreadPDFs.Start();
                }

                if (dsHeader.Tables[3].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Thread FourthTreadPDFs = new Thread(() => objPDFsProcess.DoGeneratePDFsProcess(IsEDelivery, Cycleid, StmtRunDate, CycleType, dsHeader.Tables[3], writerLog, dsHeader.Tables[15], dsHeader.Tables[16], dsHeader.Tables[17]));
                    FourthTreadPDFs.Start();
                }

                if (dsHeader.Tables[4].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Thread FifthTreadPDFs = new Thread(() => objPDFsProcess.DoGeneratePDFsProcess1(IsEDelivery, Cycleid, StmtRunDate, CycleType, dsHeader.Tables[4], writerLog, dsHeader.Tables[18], dsHeader.Tables[19], dsHeader.Tables[20]));
                    FifthTreadPDFs.Start();
                }

// update in Database
 objCustStatementDAL.UpdateCycleStatusinStmtSched(StmtRunDate, Cycleid);
```

Regards,

Prasad

Comment: You are asking us to optimize your code without telling us anything about it. The best answer you'll get is: "Profile the code, see what sticks out, and see if that can be improved."

Comment: We cant help you unless you post your code as well

Comment: Contact the PDF library vendor for support.  They are the only ones that can tell you how to most effectively use their library.  And whether or not the library is thread-safe, it is pretty unusual.